# Import Excel Pivot Table to Crystal Report

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, pivot-table, crosstab

I have created a pivot table in excel with Data from a SAP Hana database and I need to import it to Crystal Reports (using the Blank Document Wizard) without loosing the formatting. In the drag and drop section I'm presented with the cells that make a reference to the cells of the Excel spreadsheet. But when importing to Crystal Report, the format in the rows and columns will lose its relative positioning. Is there a way to go around this in Crystal Reports.

**Current format:**
[image: Current format]
**Required output:**
[image: Required output]

Comment: Also, is the formatting that you refer to conditional formatting, or regular formatting. Or do you mean number formats, like formatting 1.2 as £1.20?

Comment: Thank You for your reply actually its more of the layout of the report.  If you see the picture on this link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YbkXr.png that is how it formats when I import the excel to Crystal Reports. Actually what I want is something similar to this.  but in Crystal Reports.

Comment: This is the output I am aiming for http://i.stack.imgur.com/KdMnI.png  but in Crystal Reports.  Is there a way to import this excel into crystal reports and not loose the formatting of the cells.

Comment: Where did you place the fields in crystal reports

Comment: Hello Siva I have placed the fields in the details and the page header of the report. But by doing so it looses the format I have given it in excel (Pivot Table - Tabular Layout)